# Google Maps iframe displays too quickly in Chrome. Why?

Tags: html, css, google-maps, google-chrome, iframe

This is a site that I made...
http://matiny.zxq.net/dubai.html
In Chrome, the Maps iframe appears as soon as you hover the mouse over the #container div (In other words, the menu area, and about 20px beneath it).

Here is some relevant code, since the Ctrl+U is somewhat inconvenient of a read.

**HTML:**

```
    <li class="about">
            <p class="top-content">... </p>
            <center>
              <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d231284.91692932326!2d55.22984434999998!3d25.073857950000008!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x3e5f43496ad9c645%3A0xbde66e5084295162!2sDubai!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1397322799075" width="930" height="425" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
            </center>
          </li>
```

**CSS:**

```
#container {
    height: 150px;
    width: 1300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: height .3s;
}
#container:hover {
    height: 800px;
    width: 1300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are applying CSS to the wrong element.

I guess that map should show up only when you hover on `.about` element, not the menu container (`#container`) itself.

Also, you should restructurize your markup so the map container is inside of `li` element.

Then you could do something like this:

```
li:hover .map-container, .map-container:hover
{
   display:block;
}
```

Comment: I actually figured it out while you were editing your response. Thanks, but I did it differently. I used opacity, and set it so that the opacity would show when the about <a> was hovered over.